# youtube-dl download stops on playlist with video missing

Tags: youtube-dl

I am using youtube-dl to download from a playlist for offline viewing.  The operators of the playlist have started putting a scheduled video in the playlist that causes the downloads to fail. When trying to download the videos on the playlist, when it tries to download a video that isn't available (the scheduled video), it fails and the downloads abort.

How can I have the playlist download continue when there is a missing video?

My command:

```
/share/Multimedia/temp/youtube-dl -f 'best[ext=mp4]' -o "/share/Multimedia/YouTube/TheNational/%(upload_date)s.%(title)s.%(ext)s" --restrict-filenames --dateafter today-3day --no-mtime --download-archive "/share/Multimedia/temp/dllist-thenational.txt" --playlist-end 10 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLvntPLkd9IMcbAHH-x19G85v_RE-ScYjk
```

The download results from today:

```
[youtube:playlist] PLvntPLkd9IMcbAHH-x19G85v_RE-ScYjk: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: The National | Full Show | Live Streaming Nightly at 9PM ET
[youtube:playlist] playlist The National | Full Show | Live Streaming Nightly at 9PM ET: Downloading 10 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 10
[youtube] pZ2AG5roG-A: Downloading webpage
[youtube] pZ2AG5roG-A: Downloading video info webpage
ERROR: This video is unavailable.
```

I want to playlist download to ignore the missing file and continue to the next available video.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would add these before -f

-i, --ignore-errors 
  Continue on download errors, for example to skip unavailable videos in a playlist

-c, --continue
  Force resume of partially downloaded files. By default, youtube-dl will resume downloads if possible.